# Standard and Extended messages with same identifier

Tags: can-bus

Are the two following messages are of the same type?

- Standard message, ID = '0000 0000 111'
- Extended message, Base ID = '0000 0000 111', extended ID = '0000 0000 0000 0000 00'

In other words, are these messages are of distinct message types, or are these of the same message type?

Does the standard contains details about such cases?

Comment: not sure what 'type' means in your question, one of `DATA,ERROR,REMOTE,OVERLOAD` frames?, as that does not depend on the ID I guess you are actually asking who would receive each frame

Comment: I mean the same message type. Are standard message ID 7 and extended message ID 7 are the same?

Comment: Both IDs can go in 4 different messages types (enumerated above)... maybe think how IDE bit would break the ambiguity on the receiver side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both messages have different identifiers and thus are different messages

The CAN standard says (section 8.4.2.2 Identifier field):

> The identifier field shall be composed of three segments: base identifier, extension flag and identifier extension. The length of the base identifier shall be eleven (11) bits (ID-28 to ID-18), the extension flag one bit, and the length of the identifier extension shall be eighteen (18) bits (ID-17 to ID-0). The identifier extension shall be ignored if the extension flag is logic zero (0).

This becomes more clear, when looking at the arbitration process

Standard and extended message format are distinguished by the IDE bit. For standard messaging the bit has to be dominant (0). For extended messaging, the IDE bit is recessive (1).

The CAN-standard says:

> collisions of a base format frame and an extended format frame, with both frames having the same base identifier, shall be resolved such that the base format frame prevails over the extended format frame.

Comment: I'm not asking about the arbitration process.

Comment: @LiorKogan As the purpose of the arbitration process is to distinguish between different message, this is relevant. I added another citation of the CAN-standard.

Comment: @LiorKogan The difference is the IDE bit and how the data is stored in the frame. The CAN frame uses big endian, so the bits won't be stored in the same location between standard and extended frames. See this for details: https://www.can-cia.org/jp/can-knowledge/can/can-data-link-layers/